# Problem when running Kurento Hello World with Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, kurento

I'm trying the Kurento tutorial (6.9.0) with Node.js follow [this link](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/tutorials/js/tutorial-helloworld.html)

The video of the local stream is ok but the remote stream is not work.

The error code:
`kurento-client.js:51386 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8433/kurento' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I just follow the tutorial, no code was added. 
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came into the same issue. If SSL is not used, please try http://localhost:8443/index.html?ws_uri=ws://localhost:8888/kurento .
If SSL are used in kurento-media-server and kurento-hello-world, please try https://localhost:8443/index.html?ws_uri=wss://localhost:8433/kurento .